# How to install python3.4-dev for Mac?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

I have pip and homebrew I have tried

`pip search python3.4-dev` and also `brew search python` and can't find python3.4-dev in any of them any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Pip won't install Python itself. `pyenv` can help you install any specific Python version you want. Look here:

```
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#installation
```

Then after installation, you run

```
pyenv install 3.4-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

OS X does not have this package available. However, the package list can be found on the Debian site [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python/python3.4-dev). These packages come with py3.5 by default. Just try:

```
brew install python3
```