# "Pip install" causing "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install pygame within PyCharm. When I run `pip install pygame` in the PyCharm terminal I get `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`.

I tried what they explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet), but my results were unsuccesfull. When I ran `sudo apt-get install python-dev` as well as `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` I got `sudo: apt-get: command not found`.

I'm using macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5 by the way. I'm using the anaconda interpreter within PyCharm.

When I go to the macOS terminal and run `pip install pygame` I already have it installed, but it doesn't seem to sync with the PyCharm anaconda interpreter. When running `pip list` in both of the terminals I get completely different results.

I'm a beginner so please forgive me if this is unclear or if I'm doing something obviously wrong here.

Comment: apt-get is a tool for Debian/Ubuntu Linux systems and their derivatives. You need to find out how to install packages for MacOS (a quick google suggests that it's called "Homebrew")

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41743825/1693086) question, the dev version comes built-in with python3 itself. You can try `brew install python3` for that.